# Locus of centers of circles through a given point and tangent to a given line

Tags: geometry

> I want to find the locus of points of the centers of circles that pass through some point, say $(x_0,y_0)$, and are tangent to some line, say $Ax + By - C = 0$.

I guess the locus is going to be some sort of parabolic figure.

How can I prove this?

Comment: Do you know the [focus-directrix definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola) of the parabola?

Comment: If not, just slog away using coordinates. Suppose the circle touches the line at a point $(a,b)$. Then you know that its centre must lie on the line through $(a,b)$ perpendicular to $Ax+By-C=0$ and you know that the distance of the centre from $(a,b)$ equals its distance from $(x_0,y_0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express that the square of the distance from the center $(x,y)$ to the straight line is equal to the square or the distance of $(x,y)$ to the fixed point $(x_0,y_0)$:

$$ \dfrac{(Ax+By-C)^2}{A^2+B^2}=(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2$$

giving a second degree equation in $x$ and $y$ that is the equation of a conical curve that **must** be a parabola (as you guessed) with focus $(x_0,y_0)$ and the straight line as its directrix (as @Blue has confirmed).